# Should I use strstr() to loosely validate urls before passing them to preg_match()?

Tags: php, preg-match, strstr

I am writing a function to parse some videosites urls in order to generate embedding html:

```
if (strstr($url, 'a.com')) {
    $from = 'a';
} elseif (strstr($url, 'b.com')) {
    $from = 'b';
} else {
    return 'Wrong Video Url!';
}

if ($from == 'a') {
    // use preg_match() to retrieve video id to generate embedding html
    if (preg_match('#^http://a\.com/id_(\w*?)\.html$#', $url, $matches)) {
        // return video embedding html
    }
    return 'Wrong a.com Video Url!';      
}

if ($from == 'b') {
    if (preg_match('#^http://b\.com/v_(\w*?)\.html$#', $url, $matches)) {
        //return video embedding html
    }
    return 'Wrong b.com Video Url!';
}
```

My purpose of using `strstr()` is reducing calls of `preg_match()` in some situations, for example if I have `b.com` urls like this: `http://www.b.com/v_OTQ2MDE4MDg.html`, I don't have to call `preg_match()` twice.

But I am still not sure if this kind of practice is good or if there is a better way.

Comment: For help with `regex`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900004/turn-plain-text-urls-into-active-links-using-php/17900021#17900021

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do an alternation? (At least in this case.)

```
'#^http://(?:a\.com/id|b\.com/v)_(\w*?)\.html$#'
```

That's one `preg_match`, and zero `strstr`s.

Also, not that it is a big danger in this case, but escaping the dots when they should be dots is generally a good idea; your regexp will match `"http://bacom/v_id_xhtml"` (with `"id_"` captured by `(\w*?)`).

If you can't make "one pattern that fits all" (and it's actually a bad idea if you have many options, because your legibility goes down the drain), use a pattern to extract the site name, then do a `switch` on it. It will then just be two `preg_match`es, and zero `strstr`s, no matter how many patterns you have.